# How update column in table with array

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my code :-

```
public static final String[] strArray = {
    "347",
    "87",
    "666",
    "102",
    "430",
    "26",
    "488",
    "654",
    "1230",
    "597"
};


for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
values.put("id", strArray[i]);
DB.update("book", values, "_id between 1 and 10", null);
}
```

This results with message : Sorry Only The Last element In Arry.
 See below picture :

[image]

All I want to do is, to update the column id with strArray. I want to add all strArray in column id where `_id` between 1 to 10 
Please, can any one help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code updates all the rows in each iteration of the `for` loop because of the condition `_id between 1 and 10`, so the final result is the update of the last iteration.
Instead update only 1 row each time:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    values.put("id", strArray[i]);
    DB.update("book", values, "_id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(i + 1)});
}
```

Comment: the result of id= is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  I want like in strArray 347,87,666,102,430,26,488,654,1230,597

Comment: This: `values.put("id", strArray[i]);` sets the value to be updated. If your list is as you posted in the code then there is no case the results to be: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: the values of id from 1 to 10 is empty only _id is ready  so i want fill id with values of strArray

Comment: I have a ready database whith data Except the field " id " is empty so  I want to fill it with the strArray data , Sorry correct my code

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do and this is what the code does. Are you sure that you are looking at the table as it is in the device? How do you check the updated values?

Comment: yes I tested the code with my db in my device and the results was 1,2,3 etc not that in strArray and copied the db to my pc and open it with Db Browser for sqlite

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Nowhere in this code you can find values 1,2,3,... to update the table. Unless the values in the list are: 1,2,3,... becuase there is this line: `values.put("id", strArray[i]);` that sets the value of the column `id` to `strArray[i]`.